Probability that all white balls ($20$) will be drawn before all black ones ($10$) if there are also green balls ($5$) in the urn.
From an urn containing $20$ white, $10$ black and $5$ green balls, draw one ball at a time without returning. Determine the probability that at the time of the last white ball is drawn, at least one black ball will remain in the urn.
If it was with returning, I could count sequences of draws  in which $20$ occurrences of white ones would be mixed with $9$ occurrences of black ones and the last one would be black (I would separate $6$ scenarios with different numbers of green balls being mixed with white and black ones). However, here, the probability changes with each draw since we don't return ball to the urn. Therefore I have no idea how to do that.

There are $30$ significant balls.  Each of them has an equal chance of being the last one seen.

Note:  I don't understand what the question means if you have replacement.

Wow, that changed my perspective. So the probability is simply $\frac{10}{20+10} = \frac{1}{3}$? Because the last ball drawn, that belongs to the set of black + white balls, as each other ball from that set, will be black with probability of $\frac{1}{3}$.

Yep, that's all there is to this.

If you like:  you can post your own solution below.  That way, people here can check your work and the site can close the question.

As mentioned by @lulu, there are $30$ significant balls and each of them has an equal chance of being the last one seen. Therefore, the answer is simply $\frac{10}{20+10} = \frac{1}{3}$. The last black / white ball drawn as each other ball that can be black or white will be black with probability of $\frac{1}{3}$
